# How to write values to many2many field

Tags: python, odoo-10

I want write a list of values to `many2many` field in compute function.

```
class procont(models.Model):
    _name='pro.cont'
    unit_ids= fields.Many2many('pro.unit',string="Units",compute="get_units",store=True)
```

Above is the declaration

```
    def get_units(self):
    if self.unit_line:
        ls=[]
        for line in self.unit_line:
            ls.append(line.unit_id.id)
        self.unit_ids=self.env['pro.unit'].browse(list(set(ls)))
```

when I print `self.unit_ids`, I get values in terminal but does not show it in the form view. In form view the field is bank

```
def get_units(self):
    if self.unit_line:
        ls=[]
        for line in self.unit_line:
            ls.append(line.unit_id.id)
        self.write({'unit_ids':[(6,0,ls)]})
```

When I try above code I get following error:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
```

LINE 2: ...ntract_pro_unit_rel.pro_cont_id IN () AND pro...

Comment: `self.write({'unit_ids':[(6,0,ls)]})` -  works for dicts?

Answer (score 0):

print 'ls' just to check if you have the ids inside of it.

then try this code to write on Many2many:

```
self.unit_ids = [(6,0,ls)]
```

Hope this help...